# Flask uWSGI - ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, werkzeug

I'm using **Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)**

I am trying to learn `uWSGI`. I am able to get a "Hello World" `Python` `uWSGI` app started from this tutorial: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application

Now I want to make a "Hello World" `Flask` app. When I run:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ImportError: No module named request
```

I tried `pip install -U Werkzeug` but that didn't work. The `Werkzeug` docs say:

*"Werkzeug requires at least Python 2.6 to work correctly. If you do need to support an older version you can download an older version of Werkzeug though we strongly recommend against that. Werkzeug currently has experimental support for Python 3."*

I am using Python 2.7.11, so I am not sure why `werkzeug` is trying to use `urllib.request` instead of `urllib2`.

---

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.13.1 (64bit) on [Sun Jun  5 17:31:43 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) on 05 June 2016 16:36:34
os: Darwin-15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: Johns-MacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /Users/JohnsMacBook/Dropbox/DEV/PyDev/flask-nginx
detected binary path: /Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 709
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:3031 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7f8531c09740
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 415200 bytes (405 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "/Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ImportError: No module named request
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 9870)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 9871, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 9872, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 9873, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 9874, cores: 2)
*** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:9191 fd: 15 ***
```

Comment: maybe you can show us some code? post a verifiable example? rather than point us towards the tutorial. thanks

Comment: Run `pip -V` to check which version of python and pip you are using. I believe that `urllib.request` only exists in python 3. So something seems to be messed up here. You might have to uninstall some pip packages and reinstall them if you have the wrong version.

Comment: Your traceback says `Python version: 2.7.10`, but elsewhere you say `python 2.7.11`. Seems like there's a mixup somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something messed up with your python version. This is the source code from [`werkzeug.http.py`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0.11-maintenance/werkzeug/http.py#L25). The first `import` should work if you have python 2.x, the second should work with python 3.

```
try:
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
```

For some reason your python version has neither the python 2 `urllib2` nor the python 3 `urllib`.

I'm not familiar with Anaconda python, but could it be that the installation has been messed up somehow?

Comment: You're right there has to be a mix up somewhere. When I run `python --verision` I get `Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)`. `pip -V` gives me `pip 8.1.1 from /Users/JohnsMacBook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`. When I enter the Python shell I get `Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58)`.

I have no idea where 2.7.10 could be coming from.

Comment: @jdesilvio did you find a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing similar problem with my Anaconda python